# If I make an HTML5 app with the Ubuntu SDK, will it work on Android?

Tags: application-development

If I develop an HTML5 app with the Ubuntu SDK, how easy would it be to port that to other mobile platforms, like Android?

One of the reasons I would want to use HTML5 would be potentially the easy of reusing that same code base elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about Ubuntu SDK, but there is an open source framework named [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) that is exactly what you need. You can develop cross-platform app with solely html5, javascript and css.

Answer (score 3):

If you use **only** the Cordova (PhoneGap) APIs, then yes it should.

If you use the Ubuntu  HTML5 UI theme, or one of the Ubuntu platform APIs (Content Hub, Alarms, Online Accounts), those will not work on Android.